# django elasticsearch-dsl 7.1 check connection before send data to elastic

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

i have some problem with integration of elasticsearch-dsl to django app

this is my documents.py

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document, fields, Index
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry
from .models import CustomerTransaction, CustomUser
# from django.conf import settings

customerTransaction = Index('core_custrans')
customerTransaction.settings(
    number_of_shards=1,
    number_of_replicas=0
)


@registry.register_document
class CustomerTransactionDocument(Document):
    user_emet = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'slug': fields.TextField(),
        'num_cni': fields.TextField(),
    })
    user_recep = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'slug': fields.TextField(),
        'num_cni': fields.TextField(),
    })

    class Index:
        name = 'custrans'

    class Django:
        model = CustomerTransaction
        fields = [
            'type_trans',
            'montant',
            'solde_pass',
            'solde_actual',
            'date_trans'
        ]

        def get_instances_from_related(self, related_instance):
            return related_instance.customertransaction_set.all()


@registry.register_document
class CustomUserDocument(Document):

    class Django:
        model = CustomUser
        index = 'core_customUsers'
        fields = [
            'slug',
            'num_cni',
        ]

        ignore_signals = True

    class Index:
        name = "customuser"
```

i want to know how can i check the availability of elastic before saving data in elasticseach to avoid this exception

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff6a6890a60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff6a6890a60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

i want to check availability of elastic before saving 
regards! 
-:)